# How to replace a url in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to replace a URL with another while loading.
I have written the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var executed = false;
     if (!executed) {
        executed = true;
        window.location.href = window.location.pathname + '?'+'bc';
            }
</script>
```

But it's not working correctly. It's loading again and again. It doesn't stop.

Comment: Changing the URL will cause the browser to direct the user to that location, hence causing an infinite loop. You should use `window.history` states instead: http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

Comment: well it would load again and again since the variable is reset on page load.Try to keep executed in some cookie

Answer (score 3):

The `executed` variable is not kept when going to the new page. Even if it were, `var executed = false` just sets it to false again :p

Try this instead:

```
if( !window.location.search.match(/\?bc$/)) {
    window.location.href = window.location.pathname+"?bc";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just you variables resets after page reload. Try to check GET params like this:

```
if (window.location.search.indexOf('?bc') === -1) {
  window.location.href = window.location.pathname + '?bc';
}
```